# 日本語に違和感: 破損したものに関するフィードバック

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/give-feedback についてです。

「破損したものに関するフィードバック」ではなく、「バグについてのフィードバック」にした方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

原文がどうなっているのかを見たところ

https://stackoverflow.com/help/give-feedback

> Where can I post feedback about something that’s broken or an idea I have for a feature?

という表記ですね。

"something that’s broken" を「バグ」とするのは個人的には限定しすぎに感じます。
次のような表記ではどうでしょうか？

```
現在「破損したものに関するフィードバックや、機能に関するアイディアはどこに投稿したらいいですか?」
```

↓

```
更新「おかしなところを見つけたときの報告や、機能に関するアイディアはどこに投稿したらいいですか?」
```